# Unable to upload a track using the soundcloud API larger than 7MB

Tags: soundcloud

I am unable to upload any tracks larger than about 7MB (413 Request Entity Too Large is returned). This functionality was previously working and the [soundcloud api states that tracks can be upto 500MB](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#uploading).

Here is an example using curl with a successful upload(4.9MB) and an unsuccessful one(7.4MB)

I have provided dropbox links to the tracks(my own production, so no copyright issues!!!) if anyone wants to try to replicate. You will need to add your oauth_token.

successful upload = [4900kb_307sec_128kbps_44100hz.mp3](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3146778/tunes/4900kb_307sec_128kbps_44100hz.mp3)

```
curl -i -X POST "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json" \
           -F 'oauth_token=********' \
           -F 'track[asset_data]=@4900kb_307sec_128kbps_44100hz.mp3' \
           -F 'track[title]=A 4.9MB track' \
           -F 'track[sharing]=public'

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date
Age: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2013 18:22:57 GMT
Location: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/118866401
Server: nginx
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cacheable: NO:Cache-Control=no-cache
X-Runtime: 436
X-Varnish: 3652774389
Content-Length: 1623
```

unsuccessful upload = [7400kb_307sec_192kbps_44100hz.mp3](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3146778/tunes/7400kb_307sec_192kbps_44100hz.mp3)

```
curl -i -X POST "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json" \
          -F 'oauth_token=********' \
          -F 'track[asset_data]=@7400kb_307sec_192kbps_44100hz.mp3' \
          -F 'track[title]=A 7.4MB track' \
          -F 'track[sharing]=public'   

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2013 18:23:21 GMT
Server: ECS (lhr/4799)
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
```

thanks

Comment: Soundcloud have fixed this issue - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue with soundcloud. Seems to be an issue in their nginx.conf (webserver 
configuration).

Please contact [Soundcloud support](http://developers.soundcloud.com/support) for developers.

Answer (score 0):

Was an issue in SoundCloud API routing. Has been fixed now.

For details see comments at:
[Soundcloud: increased 413 failures (Request Entity Too Large) on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830695/soundcloud-increased-413-failures-request-entity-too-large-on-upload)