# Soundcloud: increased 413 failures (Request Entity Too Large) on upload

Tags: php, http, upload, soundcloud

Spreaker is an audio broadcasting platform with auto-sharing capabilities. When our users create a new audio, we can share it to multiple platforms (including SoundCloud). We daily upload hundreds/thousands of audio tracks to Soundcloud.

On **November 4th** we started tracking an increasing number of **413 failures on upload** (10x than average on previous weeks). Uploaded files have a size of **few tens of MB** (if I'm not wrong the SoundCloud limit is 500MB) and users we checked had enough audio space on their SoundCloud accounts.

Soundcloud, have you changed anything on your server-side on November 4th?

*Note*: we use the PHP library (https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud) and it's updated to the latest release.

**[WAS RESOLVED]**: was an issue in the SoundCloud routing that has been fixed. Thanks.

**[ISSUE AGAIN]**: on November 8th, the problem started happening again.

Comment: Why not to ask Soundcloud directly?

Comment: We're getting the same thing with our app, and it also started on November 4th 2013! I notice there's an update listed on the SoundCloud server status page on that date.. not sure if it could be related: http://status.soundcloud.com/day/2013/11/04

Comment: @namikiri It sends you to StackOverflow when you visit the SoundCloud API support. Their team answer questions on SoundCloud apparently: http://developers.soundcloud.com/support

Comment: @BT643 Yes, they did a deploy on Nov 4th, but the listed changes looks not related to this issue and I guess they push changes every day to prod.

Comment: @BT643 oh, I did'nt know, sorry.

Comment: i have posted a similar issue with replication instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820189/unable-to-upload-a-track-using-the-soundcloud-api-larger-than-7mb

Comment: @jamesshipton have you tried to ping SoundCloud? I sent them a couple of Tweets without any reply.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the report. We just changed the routing for api.soundcloud.com. That should fix the upload problems. Please let me know if not.

Comment: @arbovm We're still getting the issue!

Comment: @arbovm Same here... error appeared again.

Comment: Marco and @BT643: Sorry, should be fixed again.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same issue and had contact to soundcloud today (7th November 2013).

> "I have spoken with our developers and they are rolling back a change that they made in approximately > 15 minutes. Can you try to upload to SoundCloud after that time (about 13:15 CET) "

They made a rollback of their nginx configuration. For us this solved the problem.

Hope this helps some of you.

Simon

Comment: We're still getting the issue today. Is it still working for you?

Comment: Hi, yes it is still working. If you can reproduce it, contact soundcloud developer support.